# Generate any random number from a CDF in python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I have a piece of python code that is suppose to generate a random number from a `CDF` distribution, but the random numbers it produces are only 8 different values. I am wanting any value with in the range of numbers to be produced, with there been a bias around the number with the number that occur the most frequent in the distribution.

Heres my code:

```
import sys
import scipy.stats
import numpy


def CDF_Random(N,NE,E,SE,S,SW,W,NW,Iterations):


    WindDir = (0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315)
    Freq=(N,NE,E,SE,S,SW,W,NW)

    cdf=scipy.stats.rv_discrete(values=(WindDir,Freq))

    cdf_rand=cdf.rvs(size=Iterations)    
    return (cdf_rand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = float(sys.argv[1])
    NE = float(sys.argv[2])
    E = float(sys.argv[3])
    SE = float(sys.argv[4])
    S = float(sys.argv[5])
    SW = float(sys.argv[6])
    W = float(sys.argv[7])
    NW = float(sys.argv[8])
    Iterations = float(sys.argv[9])
    numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=Iterations)
    sys.stdout.write(str(CDF_Random(N,NE,E,SE,S,SW,W,NW,Iterations)))
```

I use Cmd Prompt to run and display the code, I use the following command:

```
python  C:\Users\...\CDF.py 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.93 0.01 0.01 10
```

I get this result returned

```
[225 225 225 225 225 225 225 225 225 225]
```

I was wanting a result more like

```
[220 230 225 222 215 240 220 225 231 235]
```

If was to run the code for more Iterations I would get results including 0 45 90 etc. But these are all the exact numbers I put in, which i don't want.

Should I be using a histogram or empirical CDF or something completely different

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You want a continuous, not a discrete distribution. And you need to figure out what the PDF of your distribution should be, in a more specific way than "with a bias around the most frequent value."

Comment: Given that you are modelling wind directions, you probably want to use a [von Mises distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.vonmises.html) which was created for just this purpose. You will have to convert between radians and degrees and pick a suitable dispersion value (`kappa`), but otherwise, it does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Jaime I have taken your advice and have been trying to generate a continuous distribution but I am struggling to get it to work I have tried this [document](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous) but I have tried numerous  `parameters` with no luck. Which parameter is defined by the PDF?  I keep `receiving a recursion depth error`, I tried reseting the resetting the recursion limit, 
`sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)`, it didnt work.